# hpricot add attribute to a HTML tag?

Tags: html, ruby, tags, hpricot

Can someone please explain how to add a custom attribute to an HTML tag using Ruby with Hpricot gem?

I have a tag that looks like this:

```
<div class="test" id="tag1" style="">
```

and I want to add a custom integer attribute called 'Readable=0' so it looks like this:

```
<div class="test" id="tag1" style="" readable=0>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
element.set_attribute "readable", "0"
```

Or if you have a `Hpricot::Elements`:

```
elements.set "readable", "0"
```

Comment: got a syntax error: "undefined method `set' for #<Hpricot::Elem:0xb72ee64c>"

Comment: @dpigera How are you getting the element? If you have a Hpricot::Elem you have to use set_attribute (like if you're using `doc.root`), but if you have a Hpricot::Elements, use set.

Comment: I'm getting the parent of a tag using: element=@file.search("p").last.parent

Comment: element.set_attribute did the trick!! thanks for the help jtbandes. I really appreciate it :-)